# ffmpeg cut video in an HLS stream, pauses playback

Tags: ffmpeg, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have this playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
```

And I want to insert a cut clip as the stream is being generated that is a bit shorter than the normal 6s length (between 1s and 3s).

So the stream looks like this.

```
stream136.ts
#EXTINF:7.133333,
stream137.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:3.68,
cutstream20.ts
#EXTINF:6.933333,
stream21.ts
#EXTINF:5.2,
stream22.ts
```

VLC plays through the discontinuity with a pretty terrible hiccup, and AVPlayer on iOS is stopping at the discontinuity entirely. If I remove the cut clip, playback is smooth.

How can I create a cut segment or modify the playlist to allow playback on iOS?

The cut command looks like this:
`ffmpeg -y -i file.ts -ss 3 -c:v copy -c:a copy cut.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` is the maximum duration so the lower value is not a problem.

Each segment must start on a keyframe (more precisely in the case of MPEG-TS with a PAT/PMT followed by an IDR).

Since you are seeking to some arbitrary timestamp and copying the existing encoding it's likely your segment doesn't start with a keyframe thus causing issues.

You can try putting the `-ss` parameter *before* the `-i` as it will parse the input using keyframes when stream-copying ([wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)).

Comment: Even with -c:v libx264 I see stutter, and that should start on a keyframe, right?

Comment: Encode both A/V. And you need a discontinuity tag after the cut too

Comment: AFTER the cut! That could *definitely* be it. Will test.

Comment: Brilliant. `-c:a libvo_aacenc` and an extra discontinuity and playback is smooth again.